# How can I rewrite this query? Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I am using CTE in order to bring multiple fields and then calculate ratios between those fields. I also using left join table calendar to bring all months in my SSRS report even though there is no data for the future months. My problem is that fields 'Binds NewBusiness','Binds Renewal','Binds Rewrite' have to come from another table and also need to be broken down by months. 
How can I bring those fields so I can use them in a final select statement of my CTE and also break them down by months.
How can I rewrite this query?

```
 ;WITH cte_Debra
    AS
    (
        SELECT      underwriter,
                    --ControlNo,
                    (
                    SELECT
                            SUM(CASE WHEN PolicyType = 'New Business' THEN Premium ELSE 0 END) as 'Binds NewBusiness',
                            SUM(CASE WHEN PolicyType = 'Renewal' THEN Premium ELSE 0 END) as 'Binds Renewal',
                            SUM(CASE WHEN PolicyType = 'Rewrite' THEN Premium ELSE 0 END) as 'Binds Rewrite'
                    FROM    ProductionReportMetrics 
                    WHERE   YEAR(EffectiveDate)= 2016 AND CompanyLine = 'Ironshore Insurance Company'
                    ) as Binds,

                    COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'New Business' THEN ControlNo  END)  as      'Submitted - New Business',
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'Renewal' THEN ControlNo  END)       as      'Submitted - Renewals',
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'Rewrite' THEN ControlNo  END)       as      'Submitted - Rewrite',
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'New Business' THEN ControlNo  END)+COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'Renewal' THEN ControlNo  END)+COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'Rewrite' THEN ControlNo  END) as 'Submitted - ALL',    


                    COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'New Business'   AND QuotedPremium IS NOT NULL THEN ControlNo  END)          as  'Quoted - New Business',
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'Renewal'        AND QuotedPremium IS NOT NULL THEN ControlNo  END)          as  'Quoted - Renewals',
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'Rewrite'        AND QuotedPremium IS NOT NULL THEN ControlNo  END)          as  'Quoted - Rewrite',
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'New Business'   AND QuotedPremium IS NOT NULL THEN ControlNo  END)+COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'Renewal'     AND QuotedPremium IS NOT NULL THEN ControlNo  END)+COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'Rewrite'     AND QuotedPremium IS NOT NULL THEN ControlNo  END) as 'Quoted - ALL',

                    b.MonthNum,
                    b.YearNum,
                    b.MonthName

        FROM        tblCalendar b  
        LEFT JOIN   Test_Plaza_ClearanceReport a ON b.MonthNum=Month(a.EffectiveDate)    
                    AND b.YearNum = YEAR(a.EffectiveDate)
                    AND a.Underwriter ='Brown, Debra'
        WHERE       b.YearNum = 2016
        GROUP BY
                        b.MonthName,
                        b.MonthNum,
                        b.YearNum,
                        --ControlNo,
                        underwriter
    )

    select          Underwriter,
                    MonthNum,
                    YearNum,
                    MonthName,
            [Binds - NEW BUSINESS],[Binds - RENEWALS],[Binds - REWRITE],  -- Binds without Total

            [Submitted - New Business], [Submitted - Renewals], [Submitted - Rewrite],                          --submitted 
            [Submitted - ALL],                                                                                  --   submitted ALL

            [Quoted - New Business], [Quoted - Renewals], [Quoted - Rewrite],                                   -- Quoted
            [Quoted - ALL],                                                                                     -- quoted ALL

            [Bound - NewBusiness],[Bound - Renewals],[Bound - Rewrite],                                          --Bound
            [Bound - ALL],                                                                                      -- Bound ALL

            [Declined - NewBusiness],[Declined - Renewal],[Declined - Rewrite],                                 --Declined
            [Declined - ALL],                                                                                   --Declined ALL 
        --and so on 

     FROM cte_Debra
```

The desired result would look like that:
[image]

and those three fields circled in red have to come from another table. Common columns are ControlNumber and PolicyNumber

Comment: Oleg you are asking how to add another table that we have no knowledge of its structure/fields etc. and that is a lot to look through as well.  I would suggest proving schema sample data and desired result as well as dumbing down the tsql some so that you are only dealing with 1 example of each of your issues (e.g. you don't nee to show 10ish calculated rations only 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a lot of detail but to give you an idea, you'd need to JOIN your other table (let say BINDS) with the SUMs that you need grouped by the YEAR and MONTH. Your data would need some date field to match the month/years in your current query.

Something like:

```
SELECT ...
FROM DATE_TABLE D 
LEFT JOIN cte_Debra AS C ON D.MONTH = C.MonthNum AND B.YEAR = C.YearNum
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT MONTH(DATE_FIELD) AS B_MO, YEAR(DATE_FIELD) AS B_YEAR, SUM(NEW_BUSINESS) AS NEW_BUSINESS, SUM(RENEWALS) AS RENEWALS, SUM(REWRITE) AS REWRITE 
    FROM BINDS 
    GROUP ON MONTH(DATE_FIELD), YEAR(DATE_FIELD) 
    ) AS B ON B.B_MO = C.MonthNum AND B.B_YEAR = C.YearNum
```

Since you want all dates, I would start with your date table - or you could RIGHT JOIN it afterwards.

You may also want to JOIN on your Underwiter as well (you'd need to include that field in the BINDS table's SELECT and ON statements.

Comment: Thanks. And when would I use my Calendar table(LEFT JOIN) in order to bring all months even if there is no data?

Comment: You shouldn't LEFT JOIN **to** the Date table - otherwise only the dates that have data match. I have updated my answer adding a DATE table as the starting table.

Comment: `;with cte_debra
AS
(
SELECT 
FROM ClearanceReport
WHERE
GROUP BY
)
SELECT Underwriter,MonthNum
FROM Calendar c LEFT JOIN cte_Debra d on c.MonthNum = d.MonthNum
LEFT JOIN ( 
SELECT MonthNum, sum(...
FROM ProductionReport
GROUP BY MonthNum
) as P on b.MonthNum = p.MonthNum
WHERE
GRoup by...`

Comment: I am confused, sorry

Comment: Your query above looks like it's OK so far. You might need to add the year in the JOIN's ON clause (`c.YearNum = d.YearNum`). You don't have a **b** table (`b.MonthNum = p.MonthNum`) - change it to **c** or **d**. Then add your SUMmed values from P in the `SELECT...`